# Why i'm getting WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER when making a POST request to a HTTPS Server?

Tags: ssl, flutter

## My app does a lot of HTTP requests to a server. After installing a SSL certificate on it, the app broke.

My server is running Ubuntu with Nginx hosting PHP code (using the certificate and working) and "proxy-ing" the app server code written in NodeJS. It was working until I changed to HTTPS.

My POST Request typical usage:

```
var jsonRequest = //Some JSON.
Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'};
var response = await http.post(urls['auth'], body: jsonRequest,headers: headers);
```

*The error I get:*

```
E/flutter (25875): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
E/flutter (25875):      WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:242))

E/flutter (25875): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:33:23)
E/flutter (25875): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25875): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:169:38)
E/flutter (25875): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25875): #2      BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:54:7)
E/flutter (25875): #3      post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:70:16)

...
```

Comment: Typically, this happens when an HTTPS client reaches an HTTP endpoint, hence not getting proper TLS at all. Make sure there is a proper TLS (HTTPS) server at the URL you use. Easy to test with curl, wget, openssl s_client or any online TLS webserver checkers.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with curl and got the same error. Looks like I was connecting directly to the node (HTTP) server instead of NGINX, changed the port and it went away.

Comment: In flutter 2.0 fixed same issue by passing Url(...) instead of Url.parse(...) to http.post method.

Answer (score 21):

As @Patrick mentioned in the comments, this is the result of TLS mismatch.

General thumb rule: If the server (API) is based on `https` (TLS) then the client should connect using `https`. If the server uses `http` (non-TLS) then the client should use `http` to connect to it.

In your case, seems like the API you are trying to hit is an `http` type hence from your flutter app you should use:

```
Uri.http(baseUrl, endPointUrl)
```

Comment: my https server is receiving http requests from unknown clients. My netty engine is throwing a lot of garbage lines in log file because of this. Is there a way to catch the netty exception or alternatively block http requests to https server? I am using KTor

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using https:// but havent installed SSL certificate. So try to use http:// instead of https://.
This work in my case.
hope also work on your side.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

the result is this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.contact_wsp">
   <application
        android:label="contact_wsp"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
```