# Google Cloud Run TLS exception on dart

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, tls1.2, google-cloud-run

I've deployed a node.js service (REST API) in GCP Run and I'm having issues with the TLS handshake in Flutter.

```
Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:242))
```

The code that I'm trying to use is:

```dart
static Future<http.Response> get(String url, {Map<String, String>? headers}) async {
    final _headers = await _addAuthHeader(headers); //appends the authorization header (not used right now)
    final out = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: _headers); //this throws the exception
    return out;
}
```

In GCP Run I've haven't set anything about the security other than the `allow unauthenticated calls` so I should be using the managed TLS service.

---

I've tested in the following conditions:

- `curl https://<url>` works ✅
- `curl --tls-max 1.2 https://<url>` works ✅
- `curl --tls-max 1.1 https://<url>` doesn't work ❌ (maybe Flutter doesn't support TLS 1.2?)
- In `dart` (HTTP**S** call) using **dio** package doesn't work ❌
- In `dart` (HTTP**S** call) using **http** package doesn't work ❌
- In `dart` (HTTP call) works ✅
- In `chrome` works ✅

I've tried the solutions proposed in these other posts:

- [Why i'm getting WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER when making a POST request to a HTTPS Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517116/why-im-getting-wrong-version-number-when-making-a-post-request-to-a-https-serve)
- [How to solve Flutter CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error while performing a POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285172/how-to-solve-flutter-certificate-verify-failed-error-while-performing-a-post-req)
- [Flutter on Android 7 CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED with LetsEncrypt SSL cert after Sept 30, 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69511057/flutter-on-android-7-certificate-verify-failed-with-letsencrypt-ssl-cert-after-s)

---

System information:

- Flutter version: `3.3.8`
- Dart version: `2.18.4`
- Flutter doctor: `everything fine`

Comment: same issue here

Comment: did u solve this??

Comment: I'm not facing the issue anymore now, probably due to some update/upgrade to the flutter engine or plugins. When I will have some spare time I will investigate this issue and what could have solved it.